# Override onkeypress method on OmniscriptText Element

Tags: omniscript

The OmniscriptText documentation gives following 4 methods to override via LWC. Is there a way to override onkeypress event on an OmniscriptText element? I am trying to perform a search action, when the user hits the enter key in the text element.

```
initCompVariables()
getImaskTextAttributes()
handleBlur(evt)
render()
```